# How to negate "I told everyone everything about the event."?

Tags: negation

I found several ways to negate the sentence

"I told everyone everything about the event.":

1. I told someone everything about the event.
2. I told everyone something but not all about the event.
3. It is not the case that I told everyone everything about the event.

Which one correctly negates the sentence? And why?

Thank you very much for your time,
Leon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that all of your three examples assert something that contradicts the original

> I told everyone everything about the event

as would

> I told everybody nothing about the event

> I told everybody everything about something else

However

> It is not the case that I told everyone everything about the event.

more clearly maps to the original.

Under [this definition](https://www.myenglishpages.com/english/grammar-lesson-negation.php) of negation

> Negation is the process that turns an affirmative statement into its opposite denial.

I think a key characteristic of negation is one of opposition - I think we should be able to re-negate the negation and fully recover the original

it is not clear that

> I told someone everything about the event

should be negated to the original.

> I told someone nothing about the event

would be an alternative candidate

> It is not the case that I told everyone everything about the event.

simply recovers the original meaning by removing the "not".

> It is the case that I told everyone everything about the event.

Hence I think your third option is the best.